# Lapacke in C: using dsymm, linker error

Tags: c, linker-errors, matrix-multiplication, lapacke

**EDIT including update at the end of the question.

When I try to use dsymm from LAPACKE, I get a "linker command failed" error.  (So, probably I am compiling the code wrong?)  Here is the code in question:

```
#include "matrix_multiplication_attempt.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lapacke.h"
int main ( )
{

/* 3x3 A matrix (symmetric) */
double a[] = {1,2,6,
              2,3,1,
              6,1,4};
/* 3x3 B Matrix */
double b[] = {2,3,4,
              3,6,7,
              4,7,4};
/* 3x3 C Matrix */
double c[] = {0,0,0,
              0,0,0,
              0,0,0};


char side, uplo;
int M,N, lda, ldb, ldc;
double alpha, beta,info;

side= 'L';
uplo='L';
M=3;
N=3;
alpha=1.0;
beta=0.0;
lda=3;
ldb=3;
info=8.0;

info=cblas_dsymm(side, uplo,
              M,N, alpha, a,lda,
              b,ldb,beta,c,ldc);
return info;
```

And here is the error I get:

`matrix_multiplication_attempt.c:51:10: warning: implicit declaration of
      function 'lapacke_dsymm' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    info=lapacke_dsymm(side, uplo,
         ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_lapacke_dsymm", referenced from:
      _main in matrix_multiplication_attempt-e2c0b9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I'm not experienced with C, so there is probably a simple mistake.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you, francis, the issue was that dsymm is not part of LAPACK, but in BLAS and your solution works.  Now, my updated question is: how can I link LAPACKE so that I can use both LAPACKE and BLAS routines in the same file?  One of my attempts at compiling is:

`gcc matrix_multiplication_attempt.c -o matrix_multiplication_attempt -lblas -Wall -I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include -L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/ -llapacke`

but this gives the error 
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cblas_dsymm", referenced from:
      _main in matrix_multiplication_attempt-76b8f6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: well, considering that **this post** is the **only occurrence ever** in the web for `LAPACKE_dsymm` I very much suspect this is a typo!

Comment: Wait, maybe you're right.  Maybe it should be CBLAS_dsymm?  But even when I do that, I get a linker error.

Comment: well please add that into your question. I am not a Lapack user nor a physicist, confused or not, but as far as I could Google, `dsymm` wasn't exported by lapacke.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my question.   And, yes, it's probably for the best one of us isn't confused.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect that the directory `/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/` contains a blas library which does not contains cblas. If there is a cblas library, try to link against it. It may not be the case. Indeed, if Lapack has been compiled by cmake, the CmakeLists.txt contains `option(CBLAS "Build CBLAS" OFF)` : the default mode is to build Lapack and Lapacke without compiling cblas. Hence, to build the makefile and recompile Lapack with cblas, you can use something like `cmake -DCBLAS=ON`.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to `dsyev`, the routine `dsymm` is not in the Lapack library. Indeed, it is implemented in the Blas library, in [BLAS/SRC/dsymm.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/db0/dsymm_8f_source.html). As a consequence, there is no interface to this routine in LAPACKE.

The best alternative for C programs is to link to CBLAS and use [`cblas_dsymm()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/dc4/cblas__dsymm_8c_a83a443f98665c7f270d9c1867a5c1d43.html).

Here is a sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include "cblas.h"

int main ( int argc, char **argv ){
    int i,j;

    int m=2;
    int n=3;
    double alpha=1.0;
    double beta=1.0;
    double AA[2][2]={{2,0},{0,1}};
    double BB[2][3]={{1,0,0},{1,0,0}};
    double CC[2][3]={{1,0,0},{1,0,0}};
    int lda=2;
    int ldb=n;
    int ldc=n;
    cblas_dsymm(CblasRowMajor,CblasLeft ,CblasUpper,m,n,alpha, &AA[0][0], lda, &BB[0][0], ldb, beta, &CC[0][0], ldc);

    for(i=0;i<m;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
            printf("%lf " ,CC[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am surprized to see that I compiled it successfully by: `gcc main.c -o main -lblas -Wall` . Indeed, I though it was necessary to link cblas by `gcc main.c -o main -lcblas -lblas -Wall` but not in my case.

Comment: Thanks so much, this does work for me!  (I didn't need to link cblas either.) I need to do some thinking to understand why.  Also, is there a way I can link LAPACKE routines as well?  Nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: You're welcome! To link LAPACKE, it's `-llapacke -llapack -lblas`.  The option `-L` can be used prior to -L so as to add the directory where the library has been installed, just like `-I` for headers.